# Why isn't the "Open New Page" button working in Safari for iPad (iOS 4.3.5)?

Tags: safari, ipad

In my recently acquired iPad2, the Safari "Open Page" button is not working. All the rest of the buttons work fine, except this one... The oddest thing is that when I "long-tap" a link and choose "Open in a new page", the animation shows all the other pages (though I can't tap/select/close any of them) before opening the new page...

Deleting the Safari cache/history works to get a new "blank" page but not to get the button working. I've tried closing Safari, powering off and even "rebooting" (home-sleep for 15 seconds) the iPad with the same result.

This was working fine before; I updated to 4.3.5 yesterday so I'm blaming it on that.

Any ideas? It's really a PITA not to basically be able to use Safari.

Comment: You should upgrade to iOS 5, it's much better and you'll probably fix you're issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the delay in getting back: Updating to 5.0 didn't fix the issue, and I noticed the "dead spot" on other apps so, to I finally took the iPad to an apple store, where they diagnosed a problem with the screen: there was a strip, around 1 cm wide that was not working properly. Got a new one and now I'm a happy camper!!

EDIT: Typo fixing (I should use spell checking!)

Answer (score 0):

It seems your iPad update to iOS 4.3.5 was not completely successful.

You can try to backup your iPad, reinstall the update and put your backup back in place (there should be no data loss).

If it still doesn't work, try to reinstall your iPad without re-applying your backup. You will lose all your apps settings.

Answer (score -2):

you can solved this problem
1. open setting - click to safari -click to open links key - click to in  background key
and show to new page open in safari